To pass or not to pass a viewmodel to a composable
According to the Googles own Architcture-sample they use the viewmodel as a input variable to the Composable.
@OptIn(ExperimentalLifecycleComposeApi::class)
@Composable
fun TaskDetailScreen(
    onEditTask: (String) -> Unit,
    onBack: () -> Unit,
    onDeleteTask: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: TaskDetailViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
) {....}

According to Googles own guidelines they say you shouldn't pass the ViewModel instances down to other composable functions.
Why pass and connect the viewmodel to the Composable in the first place?
Wouldn't it be more clean to connect the viewmodel to the compose UI screen with one upstream and one downstream instead?
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
    uiState: AppUIState,
    onEvent: (AppViewEvent) -> Unit,
) {....}

TestScreen(
    uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value,
    onEvent = viewModel::onEvent
) {....}

class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<AppUIState> = MutableStateFlow(AppUIState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<AppUIState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    
    fun onEvent(event: AppViewEvent) {....}
}

sealed interface AppUIState {
    object DoSomething: AppUIState
    data class KeyPressed(val key: String) : AppUIState
}


We can pass viewModel as  Root level Composable Screens, but we should not pass their child level composable functions.
Usually access ViewModel instances at screen-level composables, that is, close to a root composable called from an activity, fragment, or destination of a Navigation graph. This is because ViewModels are, by default, scoped to those screen level objects.
Read more about a ViewModel's lifecycle and scope here.
Try to avoid passing down ViewModel instances to other composables as this can make those composables more difficult to test and can break previews. Instead, pass only the data and functions they need as parameters.
more details refer here View Model

Yes, the ViewModel is in the same scope as the composable. However, if you have the ViewModel directly accessible inside the composable, it's easy to put some logic in the composable, because you can or pass down the ViewModel further down the tree, just for this time.
I know Google's guidelines, but I think it would be a cleaner architecture to simply send events from the composable and handle them all in a single function inside the ViewModel instead.
But this is just my opinion, and I was wondering if anyone agrees or if I'm on my own here :)
